How to remove a KDE plot on a plot with two distributions?
I created a plot with 2 distributions, using sns.histplot. I only want one kde line for one distribution.

I want to keep the orange kde plot and remove the blue kde plot, while keeping all histogram plots (blue AND ORANGE).
How can I do that?
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
sns.displot([Afa2['Normal Score Modified'],Afa2['Normal Score'],],kde=[True],stat='density')


plt.ylim(0,0.25)
plt.xlim(-3,3)
plt.show()


Only call sns.histplot for Afa2['Normal Score Modified']?

Is your question solved now? Or is it still open?

A minimal change to the code would be to simply remove the unwanted curve. You'll probably also want to set common_norm=False, as by default the histograms are normalized such that both sets together get an area of 1.
You should remove the call to plt.figure() as sns.displot creates its own figure. sns.displot can create one or more subplots (depending on its parameters). The height of the individual subplots is set via height=, and the width as height * aspect_ratio.
Here is a reproducible example.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

values = np.random.randn(5000)
Afa2 = pd.DataFrame({'Normal Score': values})
Afa2['Normal Score Modified'] = np.where(values < 0, -1, values)

g = sns.displot(data=Afa2[['Normal Score Modified', 'Normal Score']], kde=True, stat='density',
                common_norm=False, height=10, aspect=1.5)

g.set(ylim=(0, 0.50), xlim=(-3, 3))
g.ax.lines[1].remove()

plt.show()


Here is how the code could look like to first draw histplots and then one kdeplot added.
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 10))
ax = sns.histplot(data=Afa2[['Normal Score Modified', 'Normal Score']], kde=False,
                  stat='density', common_norm=False, palette=['dodgerblue', 'crimson'])
ax.set(ylim=(0, 0.50), xlim=(-3, 3))
sns.kdeplot(data=Afa2['Normal Score'], color='crimson', ax=ax)
sns.despine()


